# How do you set the default behavior of tar?

Tags: tar

I have never needed to use any other options for tar other than -cvzpf. Is there some way to set that as the default behavior?

While I recognize that it is often impossible to say *why* someone wrote a program one way as opposed to another, I do not understand why tar doesn't do things like most other command line utilities, i.e.:

```
command -options /source/path /target/path
```

Why is it instead:

```
command -options /target/path /source/path
```

Comment: *"I have never needed to use any other options for it"* So you never use the archives you create?

Comment: I never use tar to open them.

Comment: You can do `tar -cvzp /source/path -f /target/path` if you so desire, or even `tar -cvzp /source/path > /target/path`. Please first investigate what the options you're typing mean before complaining about them.

Comment: I know what it can do, and I've investigated quite a bit. My question is: why is it the default behavior? I'm not trying to complain, nor am I trying to find out if there's a way to have it not do the default. I'm assuming there is a valid reason for it to be the default, which would be useful for me to know. Why don't you at least attempt to answer the question instead of curmudgeonly downvoting it without even trying?

Comment: The first answer adequately answered the question. I would be most irritated if tar overwrote its file argument if I forgot the -x option. Also if you know what the options mean, why use -p as that's only useful in extraction.

Comment: Your "target path" here is  an argument to the `-f` option, that is why the order is this way. A usual way to use `tar` is to pipe its output to whatever compression program you want to use, that's why the default is to not require a target file. Not everyone want Gzip (or one of the few provided as options).

Comment: Ah thanks Leiaz. I get it. I'm a Mac user since 1984 and Unix since, well, OS X 10.0 beta in 2000. Especially recently that I've become a sysadmin over a Ubuntu server, and developing shell scripts and dealing very directly with unix every day all day on my Mac and through the server, I've started to wonder about some of this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: @wurtel OK, see, I had read somewhere that -p makes tar preserve permissions as it creates the archive. But what you're saying is that actually, -p only affects extraction, meaning that permissions information gets stored no matter what, and the man page seems to indicate that's the case. Am I understanding that correctly? Thanks.

Comment: `tar` always writes a complete header with all meta data. That includes permissions and owner/group. During extraction the used options determines whether those are restored (being superuser turns those on as well).

Comment: @wurtel good to know, thanks. I wonder if it captures all metadata used by Darwin/Mac OS X as well? There are some weird attributes they use like file visibility. I shall have to experiment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-cvzpf is not the default behavior for at least the following reasons.

1. -c specifies creating an archive, it is at least equally likely
     that one will want to extract an archive or view the contents of an
     archive.
2. -v specifies verbose operations, some people don't want to
    see everything
3. -p this is irrelevant for *creating* archives.
4. -f in case the user wants to pipe the output to a different device/program instead of a file (or to the default tape device in traditional Unices).

Regarding why it is not how you suggest it should be, it is historic reasons dealing with its use with tape drives and the original authors coding.

Regarding making that the default behavior, you could create an alias however, you would need a separate one for extracting files.

A separate way to change the default options with the GNU implementation of `tar` is by setting the `TAR_OPTIONS` environment variable.  Though I have found that it does not like it when you try to specify -f as one of the options.

```
export TAR_OPTIONS=-tvzp
```

Note that while you can set the options, this will cause an error if you pass tar a conflicting option.  For instance, if you have TAR_OPTIONS set as above and you try to extract an archive, you will get the following error.

```
tar: You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' option
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Comment: Awesome answer! That's just exactly what I was looking for. It's funny how many things make a lot more sense when you consider tape. Like for example, how C has .h and .m files. Consider that it takes forever to read very far into the tape, and now you're super glad that the developer kept the qty of publicly exposed stuff to a bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answers to the two questions about `tar`, but I can tell you how to set the default behaviour of any command line tools.

Using the [`alias`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Unix)) command, you can replace any word in a shell by a string. The exact use of alias depends on the shell you use. The following example works in the `bash` shell:

```
alias tar='tar -cvzpf'
```

This will replace the word tar with "tar -cvzpf". In order for bash to "remember" this, the alias command needs to be placed in a script that is executed at the start of the bash shell, for example `.bashrc`. (Some users like to collect all aliases in a seperate script, e.g. `.alias`, and call that script from `.bashrc`.)

In the `csh`/`tcsh` shell, you omit the `=` and use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes. To find out which shell you are using, type `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: Single quotes are find with `tcsh`. Actually they're fine with most shells while double quotes for instance are non-special characters in shells of the `rc` family (which don't have `alias` though).